# Using Tweepy in django for authentication and saving access token and access token secret of the user

Tags: django, tweepy

I was able to use `tweepy` to access my own account by providing consumer key & secret and access token & secret. But i am having trouble as how to authenticate other users in my web app, and save their access token & access token secret so that to monitor that users account. I am new to this and have tried everything i could find and understand. Please do share any working example if possible. Thanks in advance.

I used the given below code for accessing my own account:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token can be gotten from the user. What we did for our platform was to integrate the package `python social auth`, you can check this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html) on how to set it up. The package saves the access token and token secret of each user to a database. This tokens can be retrieved in any django view by providing `request.user.social_auth.extra_data`. Just setup and if you need any additional explanation, I am happy to help

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and implement this and if anything comes up i'll let you know.

Comment: All done. Successfully saved tokens to database. Now moving on to celery and cron job to fetch data from twitter repeatedly. Please do tell me from where i can find help on this if you have any idea. Thanks